# SSd_mobilenet loss cannot go down

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I try train ssd-mobilenet in my own dataset :
training image : 3400 with size :1600*1200
test set :800 with size :1600 *1200
tensorflow -gpu :1.13.1  gpu :4GB
cuda 10.0 cudnn 7
object: road damage like aligator crack
but after  197000 step my training loss cannot go down 2:
I need helps.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would first try with images of size 300 x 300 first, or use a library which will downscale your images and the bounding boxes.

Comment: ok but in  ssd mobilenet config  the images are to resize from original 1600 *1200 to 300*300. Thanks for response

Comment: Do bounding boxes get resized appropriately too?

Comment: I don't understand what that means "Do bounding boxes get resized appropriately too"